# Fetching parent object from child object in fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following scenario where 'Parent' contains list of 'Child' with one-to-many relationship.

```
public class Parent
{
public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
public virtual String Title { get; set; }
public virtual IList<Child> Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
public virtual String Code{ get; set; }
}
```

At certain point I have an object of 'Child' class from which i want to fetch its respective parent object. Any suggestion how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
var childId = "..."; 

Child childAlias = null;
session.QueryOver<Parent>
  .JoinAlias(parent => parent.Children, () => childAlias)
  .Where(() => childAlias.Id == childId)
  .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
  .SingleOrDefault();
```